# Каким образом по условию не NaN можно складывать столбцы в DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть DataFrame:

```
      koef  stavka  money  total
0    3.89x    0.25   0.97   0.72
1    3.06x    0.30   0.92   0.62
2    3.02x    2.29   6.92   4.63
3    3.00x    0.25   0.75   0.50
4    3.00x    0.25   0.75   0.50
..     ...     ...    ...    ...
189  4.34x   35.75    NaN    NaN
190  4.34x    0.59    NaN    NaN
191  4.34x    0.33    NaN    NaN
192  4.34x    0.29    NaN    NaN
193  4.34x    0.25    NaN    NaN
```

Колонка `total` была создана с помощью строки:

```
d['total'] = d['money']-d['stavka']
```

Но мне нужна проверка: если `money == NaN`, то по этой строчке `total` должно считаться как:

```
d['total'] = -d['stavka']
```

Попробовал это решить таким образом:

```
d['total'] = -d['stavka'] if pd.isnull(d['money']) else d['money']-d['stavka']
```

И таким:

```
d['total'] = -d['stavka'] if d['money'] == "NaN" else d['money']-d['stavka']
```

Не получилось.

Как можно такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d['total'] = d['money'].fillna(0) - d['stavka']
```